# how do i count no of dates from weeks on the given date list

Tags: java, algorithm, date

I want to find the number of dates from 1st week, 2nd week, 3 rd week and 4th week from the given dates list

```
[2017-11-22 21:41:39.0, 2017-11-27 23:15:26.0, 2017-11-27 23:26:23.0,
 2017-11-28 19:50:18.0, 2017-11-29 16:14:33.0] are dates

//By Using map  
Map<Integer, List<Date>> map;
map = inboxOutboxentityList.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(element -> 
         element.getDate().get(weekFields.weekOfWeekBasedYear())
    )
);
```

Comment: what do you mean by the number of dates?

Comment: Sir, I have bunch of date i need to bifurcate week wise and show the number of date are from same week ,  
[2017-11-22 21:41:39.0, 2017-11-27 23:15:26.0, 2017-11-27 23:26:23.0, 2017-11-28 19:50:18.0, 2017-11-29 16:14:33.0]  from above date 4th week of november there is count 1(date 2017-11-22 21:41:39.0,) and in 5th week there is count 4(dates 2017-11-27 23:15:26.0, 2017-11-27 23:26:23.0, 2017-11-28 19:50:18.0, 2017-11-29 16:14:33.0)

Comment: Can you provide exact inputs and expected output? I'm not familiar with Java Stream API but why you don't just check dd / 7 == inputWeek && mm == inputMonth while counting the matching dates with your input date interval (in x-th week of y-th month)?

Comment: You are mixing the outmoded and the modern date and time APIs. `WeekFields` are great for your task. You just need to use a modern date-time class like for example `LocalDateTime` for your dates rather then the old-fashioned `Date`for it to work.

Answer (score 1):

If you can, just forget about the long outdated `Date` class and solve your problem in pure `java.time`. Your code is not far from working.

```
    List<LocalDateTime> entities = Arrays.asList(
            LocalDateTime.of(2017, Month.NOVEMBER, 22, 21, 41, 39),
            LocalDateTime.of(2017, Month.NOVEMBER, 27, 23, 15, 26),
            LocalDateTime.of(2017, Month.NOVEMBER, 27, 23, 26, 23),
            LocalDateTime.of(2017, Month.NOVEMBER, 28, 19, 50, 18),
            LocalDateTime.of(2017, Month.NOVEMBER, 29, 16, 14, 33));
    Map<Integer, Long> countPerWeek = entities.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                    ldt -> ldt.get(WeekFields.ISO.weekOfWeekBasedYear()),
                    Collectors.counting()));
    System.out.println(countPerWeek);
```

This prints:

```
{48=4, 47=1}
```

So the count is 1 for week 47 and 4 for week 48. I believe this was what you intended. Please substitute a different `WeekFields` object if required.

If you are getting a list of `Date` objects, you will need to convert them into some modern class first. There are plenty of questions and answers about how to do that, happy searcing. As you have probably already realized, you can do it in the same series of stream operations.

Comment: Correct Answer. In addition, if doing much work with weeks of a [ISO 8601 standard week-based year](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date), add the [*ThreeTen-Extra*](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) library to make use of the `YearWeek` class.